# Endless execution with spark udf

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, geopy

I'm want to get the country with lat and long, so i used geopy and create a sample dataframe

```
data = [{"latitude": -23.558111, "longitude": -46.64439},
        {"latitude": 41.877445, "longitude": -87.723846},
        {"latitude": 29.986801, "longitude": -90.166314}
        ]
```

then create a udf

```
@F.udf("string")
def city_state_country(lat,lng):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoap")
    coord = f"{lat},{lng}"
    location = geolocator.reverse(coord, exactly_one=True)
    address = location.raw['address']
    country = address.get('country', '')
    return country
```

and it works this is the result

```
df2 = df.withColumn("contr",city_state_country("latitude","longitude"))
    +----------+----------+-------------+
    |  latitude| longitude|        contr|
    +----------+----------+-------------+
    |-23.558111| -46.64439|       Brasil|
    | 41.877445|-87.723846|United States|
    | 29.986801|-90.166314|United States|
    +----------+----------+-------------+
```

, but when I want to use my data with the schema

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- open_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- starting_lng: float (nullable = true)
 |-- starting_lat: float (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lat/long: string (nullable = false)
```

and 4 million rows, so I use limit and select

```
df_open_app3= df_open_app2.select("starting_lng","starting_lat").limit(10)
```

Finally, use the same udf

```
df_open_app4= df_open_app3.withColumn('con', city_state_country("starting_lat","starting_lng"))
```

The problem is that when I execute a display the process is endless, I don't know why but theorically should be process only 10 rows

Comment: What happens if you instead try `df_open_app3= df_open_app2.select("starting_lng","starting_lat").limit(10).cache()`

Comment: you sure it's not some networking issue instead? are the two places (where it works and where it hangs) same or in different network like works on your laptop but not when running in databricks/cloud.. add some `print()` inside udf and then compare executor logs where it works and where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the similar scenario in my environment and it's working perfectly fine with around million records.

- Created sample UDF function and dataframe with around million records.
  [image]
- selected particular columns and executed function on that.
  [image]

As Derek O suggested try by using `.cache()` while creating a dataframe co you don't need to re-read the dataframe. so, that you can reuse the cached dataframe. When you have billions of records. Since action triggers the transformations, display is the first action hence it triggers the execution of all above dataframes creations ang might causing abnormal behavior.